# Including files issue with relative paths on a linux system

Tags: php, linux, tree, directory

I have the following directory tree structure:

```
/index.php
/code/inc/variables.php
/code/inc/config.php
```

index.php is the file that is called.

On our development system in: /code/inc/variables.php, when I have the line:

```
require_once("./code/inc/config.php");
```

it doesnt work and when I have:

```
include_once('config.php');
```

it does work.

The puzzle is that the first works on our development system and the second works on our production system. And there is no difference in the tree structure on either of the two systems (both run linux, different versions perhaps).

Comment: Check the value of the include_path directive in your php.ini because relative file references in includes are relative to the entries in that, not to the directory of the current script

Answer (score 1):

If you call require_once in file **DOCUMENT_ROOT/public_html/x.php**:

```
require_once("./code/inc/config.php");
```

that's meen what it will be searched for file

*DOCUMENT_ROOT/public_html/code/inc/config.php*

if you call same require_once **DOCUMENT_ROOT/public_html/code/inc/variables.php**:

it will be searching for file:

*DOCUMENT_ROOT/public_html/code/inc/code/inc/config.php*

and of course it fails.

You can use request like this:

```
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/code/inc/config.php");
```

and it will work in all your files correctly.