# best way to include file in php?

Tags: php

my file paths was like

```
mysite/projectname/folder1/abc1/abc2/myfile.php
```

now i am working in the path

```
mysite/projectname/folder1/xyz1/xyz2/workingfile.php
```

at present i have to include myfile.php on workingfile.php

i was tried with

```
include(../../myfile.php)
```

its working.

my doubt is what is the best way to include this file ?

have seen [example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839522/php-relative-paths-and-directories) [example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3734140/including-files-issue-with-relative-paths-on-a-linux-system)

Comment: This is totally upto your requirement...  also, consider using `require` instead of `include` as `require` will halt the script right there

Comment: `require_once __DIR__ . '/../../my-file.php';`

Comment: This question has been previously answered [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8354362/what-is-the-best-practice-for-including-php-files


goodluck

Comment: Use require is wise choice and provide full directory path to the file is good to avoid mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Use dirname():

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . '/myfile.php');
```

Chaining them together will grab parents. The above code would be the equivalent of:

```
require_once('../../myfile.php');
```

Alternatively, you could also do this with a windows-friendly option (if you for some reason want your code to work on a windows machine):

```
require_once(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__))) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'myfile.php');
```